# Best place to change UINavigationBar property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want make some changes in `UINavigationBar` property **programmatically**. `- viewDidLoad:` or `-initWithNibName:` is the best place to do this and why?

Comment: programmatically mean everywhere you can change it

Comment: i know it but i asked which is the best place.

Comment: What properties? What creates and owns the navigation bar?

Comment: i want to set titleView, rightBarButtonItem and leftBarButtonItem.

Comment: i think better place is - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated for set up and - (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated for set down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`– viewDidLoad` is the ideal function to perform these kind of changes.

As the name suggests the view will be completely loaded into the memory when this function is called and should not be any problem to make these kind of changes.

I wouldn't suggest making such changes in `– viewWillAppear:` or `– viewDidAppear:` as they will be called each time the view appears. This would be helpful if you would want to change the navigation bar properties each time it appears. I think that situation is highly unlikely and hence suggest `– viewDidLoad` as it will be called only once.

`-initWithNibName:` will create your controller instance from the nib file. You can perform the operations you have mentioned in this function, but there are chances it might act weird sometimes as it might not be in the right state. Even Apple Docs suggest `"If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there."`

Comment: You did not mention about initWithNibName. what about that method?

Answer (score 0):

If yours viewControllers have different property of navigationBar you can change they next way. In UIViewController subclass override next methods:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];

    [self.navigationItem setTitleView: nil];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];

    [self.navigationItem setTitleView: titleView];
}
```

It works.